# Analytics | Measuring page velocity for page value?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to give my pages a value equal to page velocity. I'm reading through this guide which says:
https://online-behavior.com/analytics/page-velocity

"To measure Page Velocity, we will need to send an Ecommerce transaction with an arbitrary value of $1 on every pageview so it receives credit for the future pageviews as well."

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you think you should do first? A bit broad question in a way

Comment: @AnkDasCo the first thing I did was turn on eCommerce reporting

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this but the implementation 'depends' on different use cases. The blog you have shared is primarily intended for content heavy site and not ecommerce sites. The next step would be to create a completely different view so that the ecommerce numbers do not mess up your original numbers.

Second step would be to assign a page value in terms of 1 dollar to the goal pages (main content pages) or all pages depending on how you want to do it.

You just need to remember page value = (transaction value + goal value)/ unique pageviews.

Unique page views is ' the number of individual users who have loaded a given page per session'. Hope this makes sense

Comment: So you're saying, set each page as a Destination goal and, according to this article, assign $1 to each page?

Comment: how would you assign $1 to each page? setting a goal right?

Comment: Yup, that's my plan. It just seems excessive to do this to every single page. I thought I was missing something.

Comment: I can only set 20 goals per view though